Kinematics perfectly elastic collision simulation in C not working
So I am learning C and wanted to do some kinematics as a small learning project, but I do not know what is wrong with my code and why the y position (d_1) does not return to its starting point in this perfectly elastic collision.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    double v_1;
    double v_0;
    double Δv;
    double Δt;
    double t_0;
    double t_1;
    double d_0;
    double d_1;
    double Δd;
    double a;

    int elapsed_time = 0;
    t_0 = 0;
    t_1 = 0;
    v_0 = 0;
    v_1 = 0;
    a = -9;
    d_0 = 100; // starting displacement
    d_1 = 100; // current displacement, or the y position

    while (elapsed_time < 1000){

        Δt = t_1 - t_0;
        Δd = d_1 - d_0;
        Δv = v_1 - v_0;

        v_1 = v_0 + a * Δt;
        d_1 = d_0 + v_1 * Δt;

        if (d_1 <= 0)
        {
            d_1 = 0;
            v_1 = -v_1;
        }
        d_0 = d_1;
        v_0 = v_1;
        t_0 = t_1;
        t_1 += 0.1;
        elapsed_time += 1;
        printf("d_1 = %lf, v_1 = %lf, v_0 = %lf, a * Δt = %lf\n", d_1, v_1, v_0, a * Δt);

    }

    return 0;
} 

Right now it works alright even if it is a bit "jank". The idea is pretty simple; im just doing mini kinematics each time interval of 0.1. So initially nothing happens until Δt = 0.1, which then moves everything along according to the kinematic equations. Then I update the new starting point for the velocity, position so I can do it all again. Enforcing Δt = 0.1 rather than calculating t_1 - t_0 does not solve the problem either.
Here is the output I got:
d_1 = 100.000000, v_1 = 0.000000, v_0 = 0.000000, a * Δt = -0.000000
d_1 = 99.910000, v_1 = -0.900000, v_0 = -0.900000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 99.730000, v_1 = -1.800000, v_0 = -1.800000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 99.460000, v_1 = -2.700000, v_0 = -2.700000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 99.100000, v_1 = -3.600000, v_0 = -3.600000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 98.650000, v_1 = -4.500000, v_0 = -4.500000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 98.110000, v_1 = -5.400000, v_0 = -5.400000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 97.480000, v_1 = -6.300000, v_0 = -6.300000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 96.760000, v_1 = -7.200000, v_0 = -7.200000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 95.950000, v_1 = -8.100000, v_0 = -8.100000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 95.050000, v_1 = -9.000000, v_0 = -9.000000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 94.060000, v_1 = -9.900000, v_0 = -9.900000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 92.980000, v_1 = -10.800000, v_0 = -10.800000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 91.810000, v_1 = -11.700000, v_0 = -11.700000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 90.550000, v_1 = -12.600000, v_0 = -12.600000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 89.200000, v_1 = -13.500000, v_0 = -13.500000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 87.760000, v_1 = -14.400000, v_0 = -14.400000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 86.230000, v_1 = -15.300000, v_0 = -15.300000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 84.610000, v_1 = -16.200000, v_0 = -16.200000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 82.900000, v_1 = -17.100000, v_0 = -17.100000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 81.100000, v_1 = -18.000000, v_0 = -18.000000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 79.210000, v_1 = -18.900000, v_0 = -18.900000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 77.230000, v_1 = -19.800000, v_0 = -19.800000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 75.160000, v_1 = -20.700000, v_0 = -20.700000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 73.000000, v_1 = -21.600000, v_0 = -21.600000, a * Δt = -0.900000
.
.
.
d_1 = 10.900000, v_1 = -39.600000, v_0 = -39.600000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 6.850000, v_1 = -40.500000, v_0 = -40.500000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 2.710000, v_1 = -41.400000, v_0 = -41.400000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 0.000000, v_1 = 42.300000, v_0 = 42.300000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 4.140000, v_1 = 41.400000, v_0 = 41.400000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 8.190000, v_1 = 40.500000, v_0 = 40.500000, a * Δt = -0.900000
.
.
.
d_1 = 85.050000, v_1 = 15.300000, v_0 = 15.300000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 86.490000, v_1 = 14.400000, v_0 = 14.400000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 87.840000, v_1 = 13.500000, v_0 = 13.500000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 89.100000, v_1 = 12.600000, v_0 = 12.600000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 90.270000, v_1 = 11.700000, v_0 = 11.700000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 91.350000, v_1 = 10.800000, v_0 = 10.800000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 92.340000, v_1 = 9.900000, v_0 = 9.900000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 93.240000, v_1 = 9.000000, v_0 = 9.000000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 94.050000, v_1 = 8.100000, v_0 = 8.100000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 94.770000, v_1 = 7.200000, v_0 = 7.200000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 95.400000, v_1 = 6.300000, v_0 = 6.300000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 95.940000, v_1 = 5.400000, v_0 = 5.400000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 96.390000, v_1 = 4.500000, v_0 = 4.500000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 96.750000, v_1 = 3.600000, v_0 = 3.600000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 97.020000, v_1 = 2.700000, v_0 = 2.700000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 97.200000, v_1 = 1.800000, v_0 = 1.800000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 97.290000, v_1 = 0.900000, v_0 = 0.900000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 97.290000, v_1 = 0.000000, v_0 = 0.000000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 97.200000, v_1 = -0.900000, v_0 = -0.900000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 97.020000, v_1 = -1.800000, v_0 = -1.800000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 96.750000, v_1 = -2.700000, v_0 = -2.700000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 96.390000, v_1 = -3.600000, v_0 = -3.600000, a * Δt = -0.900000
d_1 = 95.940000, v_1 = -4.500000, v_0 = -4.500000, a * Δt = -0.900000

What I do not understand is why d_1 does not return to 100, since it should in a perfectly elastic collision. Right now it starts to fall again at d_1 = 97.290000, which is close but not 100. In fact, it gets worse over time. Why is this happening? I suspect it could be a rounding error, but I do not know enough about C to say for sure. If it is a rounding error, why is it happening and is there a way to fix it?

You are calculating the new velocity after a Δt of 0.1 without checking if the next collision occurs within that time period. One solution is to calculate the time to closest approach and if it's less than Δt, step to the collision and flip the sign of the velocity.

Δv is not valid C. Δ is not part of the character set that the compiler must accept, so anything can happen. A better name in standard C would be delta_v or similar. Whenever facing bugs, start with removing all forms of undefined behavior from the code.

Your simulation adds the velocity at the end of each interval of time to the distance. Real objects do not move that way. Over an interval, the velocity continuously contributes to the distance. There are several options for improving that:

Decrease the step time. This will decrease the error. Changing t_1 += 0.1; to t_1 += 0.01; will show this.

Change how the distance is updated from the velocity. A crude model of updating the distance based on the average of the starting velocity and ending velocity of each interval will work well in this circumstances, where there is linear acceleration. (In other situations, a more complicated curve fit of recent velocities might be suitable.)


You have a similar problem at the collision. You set the distance measurement to zero as if the object had collided and come to a momentary halt exactly at position zero, but you set the velocity to the negative of the velocity the object would have had if it had finished moving for the interval. You should set it to the negative of the value it would have had when it reached position zero.

IMHO, if you initialize t1 = 0 and t2 = 0, then to calculate the time interval, you should never subtract t2 - t1 as the result will give you a context in which the time doesn't go forward.
In order to provide a good environment to calculate the collision, I should switch to a reference system with the origin in the center of mass of both bodies.  This will make (0, 0) the point of collision, and simplify the huge amount of calculations you are making.  For a collision to exist, the rotation momentum of the two particles should be 0 in that reference system.  And them will collision frontwards, this means, for pure elastic collision they will depart from the origin in the reverse direction.  If you have calculated correctly the change in the reference system, and calculated the inverse transformation, to make the output will be easy.
BTW, you should initialize the variables in the declaration, this will reduce the number of statements you write, and make the program more readable.  But you are the maintainer!!!!  this is only my two cents.
